# Вызов одного метода или нескольких для нескольких действий? Python

Tags: python, ооп

**Имеется задача:** создать метод(ы) для парсинга поста в двух (пока) соц. сетях.

**Вопрос:** скажите, пожалуйста, лучше создать одну функцию, которой будет передаваться атрибут с названием соц. сети и она уже будет с помощью условий решать, какой алгоритм далее будет запущен (пример `parse_post(social_network)` **ИЛИ** создать две функции для парсинга из каждой соц. сети (пример `parse_VK_post` и `parse_TG_post`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше создать одну функцию, которая будет решать, какой алгоритм будет далее запущен. Но этот алгоритм также поместить в отдельную функцию.

```
def parse_sc(sc):
    if sc == "vk":
        parse_vk()
    if sc == "fb":
        parse_fb()
    else:
        unknown_sc()
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за Ваш ответ, а почему так лучше?

Comment: Потому что функция короткая и легко можно определить, что она делает, поскольку не захламлена кодом для каждой сети.

Comment: спасибо ... кхм кхм!

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд несколько небольших функций лучше одной большой. В идеале код функции должен помещаться на экран без скролинга. Еще один плюс такого подхода в том, что в будущем, если вы захотите провести рефакторинг ваших функций - упаковать их в отдельные классы (VkParser и TgParser) с общим интерфейсом (Parser), то вам будет проще т.к. код уже находится в разных функциях